# What happens if I rename the 'manage.py' in django?

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I have changed the 'manage.py' to 'server.py' and it worked. But what I want to know is whether it will work if I host the Django App somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what the problem is with `manage.py`. `manage.py` does not only run the server. You can also perform management commands, make translations, migrations, etc.

Comment: What advantage you would like to gain by renaming it?

Comment: I was just asking whether the name matters or not, @ArakkalAbu .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it works don't touch it :)
But it should still work.